# Is there any way to remove an item from a ListView temporarily and add again at the same index location in WPF?

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

For example let us consider I have two ListView A and B. There are 5 items in A and no items in B. Now via an add button click I am trying to remove the selected items from A and adding those items to B. Now again via a remove button click I am trying to add the selected items from B back to A. But the problem now is the items are just been added at the end, I need the items to be added exactly at the same index where it was initially.

**Initially:**

```
  A                B
Test1              -
Test2              -
Test3              -
Test4              -
Test5              -
```

**After clicking Add button:**

```
  A                B
Test3            Test1
Test4            Test2
Test5              -
  -                -
  -                -
```

**After clicking Remove button:**

```
  A                B
Test3              -
Test4              -
Test5              -
Test1              -
Test2              -
```

But I need the items test1 and test2 located in the beginning of the ListView,
like the below output:

```
  A                B
Test1              -
Test2              -
Test3              -
Test4              -
Test5              -
```

Below is the basic outline code I am using

```
private IList<String> selectedAItems
private IList<String> selectedBItems;

private ObservableCollection<String> A;
private ObservableCollection<String> B;

/// <summary>
/// Execute add command
/// </summary>
private void ExecuteAddCommand()
{
    foreach (String item in SelectedAItems)
    {
        A.Remove(item);
        B.Add(item);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Execute remove command
/// </summary>
private void ExecuteRemoveCommand()
{
    foreach (String item in SelectedBItems)
    {
        B.Remove(item);
        A.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Any help would be of much help

Regards,
Anish

Comment: Try with `collection.Insert(0, item);`. You can also store the index in your collection, instead of just the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the ListViews in the view by binding to two CollectionViewSources instead of binding to the source collections directly:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window15"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window15" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="a" Source="{Binding A}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="." />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="b" Source="{Binding B}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="." />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="lvA" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource a}}" />

        <ListView x:Name="lvB" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource b}}" Grid.Column="1" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding Add}" />
            <Button Content="Remove" Command="{Binding Remove}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This should work if you always want the strings to be listed in alphabetical order.

The other option would be to keep track of the indexes yourself somehow and use the Insert method to insert an item at a specific index rather than adding it to the end of the collectoíon: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.insert(v=vs.110).aspx.

This will get quite messy though since the number of items in the Collections as well as the index of each item is dynamic and change as you add or remove items. Sorting the items should work.